# Redirect to referring page after form submission

Tags: 8, webforms

Trying to figure out how to redirect a user back to referring page after they have completed our feedback form. So a scenario would be if im on page `foo/bar` and I click on feedback webform link on that page. I then proceed to fill out the webform and then hit submit I will then be directed back to `foo/bar` page with confirmation message displayed at top of page. Webform module does give me an option to add in a custom confirmation URL and also the ability to add in tokens. However I have had no success with current tokens as none of them redirect me back to referring page.

[image]

Would creating a custom token maybe help with resolving this issue or `hook_form_alter`? Kind of stuck on how best to approach this.

Comment: The referrer header is not always present, add instead a destination query parameter to the link pointing at the web form, which should override any url you configure. If not, you can also try to use a token, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158003/redirect-to-another-page-on-webform-submit-using-current-pagequery-token

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding destination query parameter to webform link directly and nothing happened. I also tried solutions in link you provided but they did not work. I might just have to look into custom token solution.

Comment: The linked question is for D7, but it works for D8 the same way. I've just tested it, configured "URL with message" and "<front>", navigated the browser to the webform with a destination query string contact?destination=admin/people. After submitting I got redirected to the destination url, not the front page, and I could see the message "Your message has been sent."

Comment: Yes that works, however, I need the destination query string to somehow capture the URL the user was on when thy clicked on the feedback link so that after they click on the submit button they get directed back to whatever page they were on orginally. Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: Add the current url as destination query string to the feedback link when building the page or rewrite the link in javascript. The second option is better for cache performance when the feedback link is placed on a lot of different pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think I may have found a solution. Would something like this work ok? `href="/form/feedback?destination={{ path('<current>') }}"`. Any security implications with this approach?

Comment: Yes, in a page template this should work. For other templates use a preprocess hook and add a cache context, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287038/how-do-i-make-the-same-variable-available-to-all-my-theme-files. From a security standpoint this is as secure or unsecure as the referrer header or any other information in a request, you can't trust any of it.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Great, do you mind posting the final solution as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rely on the referrer header, because clients can refuse to provide one. For this use case Drupal has implemented a query parameter `destination`. Configure the webform with a default Confirmation URL, like `<front>`, and then add the current url as destination query string to links pointing at the webform.

For example add a feedback link to nodes:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node templates.
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['feedback'] = [
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t('Feedback'),
    '#url' => new Url(
      'entity.webform.canonical',
      ['webform' => 'feedback'],
      ['query' => ['destination' => Url::fromRoute('<current>')->toString()]]
    ),
    '#cache' => ['contexts' => ['url.path']],
  ];
}
```

This overrides the configured confirmation URL and returns to the referring page after the webform is submitted.

In a page template you don't need the cache context and you can use this Twig only solution, as @PaulH has suggested:

```
href="/form/feedback?destination={{ path('<current>') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this and sorry for not posting earlier.